# Vertical spacing of text changes in a macro depending on input

Tags: line-spacing, setspace, varwidth

I defined a keynote macro to insert key ideas in my document using `varwidth`. The document is in `\doublespacing` and I have defined `\singlespacing` inside my macro. However, the correct spacing is achieved only for long sentences and not for short text like here.
[image: Variable spacing]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{setspace,varwidth,lipsum}

\newcommand{\keynote}[1]{%
    \begin{varwidth}{4cm}%
      {\singlespacing \narrowragged #1}%
    \end{varwidth}%
}

\begin{document}
  \doublespacing
  \hspace{1cm} \keynote{\lipsum[2]}
  \hspace{1cm} \keynote{This note explaining a key idea should go to at least two lines.} \hspace{1cm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to terminate the paragraph, or it will be done when the change in line spacing has already been forgotten because of the `}`; but since `\end{varwidth}` ends the paragraph anyway and you're in an environment that forms a group, you can just say

```
\newcommand{\keynote}[1]{%
   \begin{varwidth}{4cm}
   \singlespacing \narrowragged #1
   \end{varwidth}%
}
```

Why the example had that peculiarity? Because `\lipsum[2]` has a `\par` command inside it. If you used `\lipsum*[2]`, that doesn't issue `\par` you'd have seen the same problem.

Now you know why: in

```
\begin{varwidth}{4cm}
{\singlespacing\narrowragged some text to be single spaced}
\end{varwidth}
```

the paragraph "some text to be single spaced" will be built when the `}` has already undone the `\singlespacing\narrowragged` setting. Without the inner braces it's OK.

Comment: wonderful. I played around with `\par` and different environments, and it is beautiful...just shows me how much more there is to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `spacing` environment of the 'setspace' package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{setspace,varwidth,lipsum}

\newcommand{\keynote}[1]{%
    \begin{varwidth}{4cm}%
      \begin{spacing}{1}
        {\narrowragged #1}%
      \end{spacing}
    \end{varwidth}%
}

\begin{document}
 \doublespacing
  \hspace{1cm} \keynote{\lipsum[2]} \hspace{1cm} \keynote{This note
    explaining a key idea should go to at least two lines.}
  \hspace{1cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Any idea why `\singlespacing` won't work?

Comment: I don't know really. Please if you like the answer mark it as accepted by clicking the ok symbol.

Comment: thanks. I think its only fair to wait for any other answers. Otherwise, I will accept yours by tomorrow.